# Neural Network with input of 0

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Imagine you have a Neural Network with Sigmoids. It has an input x and so a node would output tanh⁡x to a connection. The connection would then output w∗tanhx where w is the weight of the connection.

The problem is, what if an input is 0 and the desire output should be something like 1? Well if the input is 0, the output of the connection would be w∗tanh0=0. So if the input is 0, then then output will always be 0 no matter how many nodes or connections you add or how much the weights on the connections are.

How would you make a simple network where an input of 0 will give you something other than 0?

Comment: You are forgetting about biases, so the output might not be zero. NNs are non-linear functions. Also your output equations are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Aside**

One thing to notice is that the function for each layer should be of the form:

`z = transpose(W) * X
output = tanh(z)`

where you are multiplying by the weight vector before passing into the transfer function (tanh). This however does not answer your question or fix your problem.

**First way**

To answer your question, you should add a bias unit to your input. One such way of doing this is to use a constant input of 1 as an input.

So if you have pseudo code: `number_of_inputs = 10` then you'd instead use pseudo code: `number_of_inputs = 11; input[10] = 1`.

This allows your output function to be of the same form as above.

**Second Way**

You can also add a bias unit outside of your transfer function. That is, your output could be of the form:

`z = transpose(W) * X
output = tanh(z) + b`

The update rule for `b` then would be based on the derivative of your loss, but not the derivative of your transfer.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a pseudo input whose value is constant 1. This input can then be used as a weighted bias for neurons in the first layer.

Answer (score 0):

The sigmoid function is not limited to **tanh(x)**; the more general form is **w*tanh(ax+c) + b**.  Yours might look something like this, where a low x value gives a result near 1.0:

> -1 * tanh(x) + 1

Weights and biases are the tools that generalize the compressions and translations of moving the sigmoid curve to the place it's needed.